# Find complex number $z$ if $arg(z^4i^{25})=arg(u)$ where $u=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}-\frac{1}{3}i$ and $|z|=6$

Tags: complex-numbers

$\arg(u)=\frac{11\pi}{6}$

$t=(z^4i^{25})=2xy(y^2+xy-2x^2)+i(x^4-4x^2y^2+y^4)$

If $\arg(z^4i^{25})=\arg(u)$ does that mean $t=u$?

Comment: Find complex number $z$ if $\arg\left(z^4i^{25}\right)=\arg(u)$ where $u=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}-\frac{1}{3}i$ and $|z|=6$:

Step 1)
$$\arg\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}-\frac{1}{3}i\right)=-\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Step2)
$$\arg\left(z^4i^{25}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{6}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\arg\left(z^4i\right)=-\frac{\pi}{6}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\arg\left(\left(6e^{\Phi i}\right)^4i\right)=-\frac{\pi}{6}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\arg\left(\left(1296e^{4\Phi i}\right)i\right)=-\frac{\pi}{6}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\arg\left(i e^{\Phi i}\right)=-\frac{\pi}{6}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$arg(z^4i^{25})=arg(u)$

$arg(z^4)+arg(i^{25})=arg(u)=\frac{11\pi}{6}$

$4arg(z)+25 arg(i)=\frac{11\pi}{6}$

$4arg(z)+25 \frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{11\pi}{6}$

Now find $arg(z)$ and $z=|z|e^{i \arg(z)}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT $\arg (z^4i^{25})=4\arg z+25\arg i$